# a function that turns [String] to (Int,Int)

Tags: haskell

ive been lurking in this website for some time so ill finally post my 1st question.
atm i have to do a school project which is to create the game Sokoban with haskell,and so far its been going good until i got to the part where i have to validate the coordinates.
they come as such
11 2
3 4
5 6
it should return "Ok"
i have a function that turns them into a tuple of ints so i can check if they point to a place inside the map ,however that function doesnt give me a nice error message if its a a or just a number, which i need it to do that, for example
a a
11 2
3 4
the message should be "1", as in error in line 1.
1 3
2
4 5
the error message should be "2" too
Is there any way to do that sort of thing, ive ran out of ideas
the function that turns from String into (Int,Int)

```
processcoordinates::[String]->(Int,Int)  
processcoordinates [x,y]= (read x,read y)  
processcoordinates xs = error "invalid format"
```

Note:the function above is applied with the map function

among the things ive already tried but failed were using something along the lines of

```
valcoor::Int->[String]->Int  
valcoor n []=-1   
valcoor n ((x,y):t)  
|isDigit x && isDigit y =valcoor (n+1) t 
|otherwise =n
```

Note:sorry first time posting a question so im making a lot of mistakes :D
ive edited this function so many times so i cant remember exactly the kind of error messages it gave although among them were
Couldn't match expected type ‘[String]’
                with actual type ‘([[Char]], [[Char]])’
 which happened when testing with actual values such as
(["1","1"],["2","2"])

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The community expects that you show your existing efforts, i.e. what have you tried, what worked and what didn't, what documentation you searched and what ideas you've had when looking for a solution etc. You should also ask specific questions that can have a clear answer, not "please assist me" or "solve this for me". I strongly suggest you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Note for downvoters: If you downvote a question of a newcomer, please add an explanation why so that the question can be improved.

Comment: What have you tried should be described in the question, and not in comments. Also giving a type signature without any explanation is far from enough. What were the details? How the function looked like? Why it didn't work? ...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Parsing&oldid=690761306) that will convert a string input into a data structure.

As this is a homework, I don't want to give you a direct answer. Rather I'd suggest you to read [Using Parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) from a great book Real World Haskell, which solves a problem very similar to yours. A parser will allow you to have nice and location-specific error messages.

Note that you probably want to treat the whole input as one `String` so that everything (including counting lines etc.) is done by the parser. So the signature you're looking would be probably something like

```
processcoordinates :: String -> Either ParseError [(Int, Int)]
```

where the left part of `Either` describes an error, and the right part a successful outcome.